# Is it possible to implement server-side paging with a WCF Service, NOT a WCF Data Service

Tags: .net, wcf, paging, wcf-data-services, data-paging

I've been experiementing with using WCF and have written a WCF Service to provide the backend for a web site. I've encountered a problem when it comes to implementing server-side paging as all the examples I've found (such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358711.aspx) all seem to use DataServiceQueryContinuation and WCF Data Services.

Whilst I appreciate I could write a WCF Data Service to return the data, it seems like extra complexity having a WCF Service for things like logins and updating user information and then a separate WCF Data Service for larger queries / reporting.

Would this be the standard practise or is there a built in mechanism for paging data via a method call from a WCF service?

**EDIT**

I've found a couple of possible methods of doing this, a simple method involving Linq's `skip` and `take` operators: [Implementing pager through WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741413/implementing-pager-through-wcf-service)
and a more complicated method:
[Best practice for WCF service with large amounts of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476337/best-practice-for-wcf-service-with-large-amounts-of-data)

I had thought that there might be a way of using WCF Service to page data like you can with a WCF Data Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474245.aspx

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are using a WCF service for all our communication with our back end server and we've implemnted paging by just passing a simple PaginDTO to a method call with properties like PageSize and CurrentPageIndex.

The result is a PagedDTO which contains the list of items and info about the total amount of pages.

We use the entity framework for our database and with Skip/Take this is really simple to implement.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Wouter, from my research this is looking like the best way of doing it. I'm just a bit surprised that paging isn't as easy as it is in a WCF Data service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474245.aspx).