# How to load 'more' data with AngularJS and a WCF WebService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, wcf

currently i am using a WCF WebService to provide data for a page with AngularJS. It retrieves all data at first time. What i want to do is to load the first n records and the on click on a button or link, image etc. i want to load the next n records and add it to my model.

How could i achieve this?

Comment: You have to change your service (e.g. adding some parameter) to achieve your goal.

Comment: ok, could be more precise please?

Comment: You should create a method in your service (e.g. `getRecords(int numRecord=0)` ) and return the specified number of record passed as parameter or all the records if parameter is 0...something like that. See articles like this for guidance: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123067/A-Simple-Sample-WCF-Service

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that. In case to have a or first n on load its ok for me. My requirement would be to load "more" or better next n data. I better add this to my post. How to go in this case?

Comment: you need pagination. There're a lot of resources inside and outside SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741413/implementing-pager-through-wcf-service or http://dzapart.blogspot.it/2013/01/wcf-pagination.html

Comment: Thank you! I now know how to implement. The second link is very detailed but i think too overloaded for my purpose. But the idea is now clear and can think about a lightweight implementation based on my needs. How can i mark a comment as helpful?

Comment: click the up arrow near the comment :) tnx (or maybe you need some reputation point...I don't remember)